# There is a section in size inspector with name Autosizing. How to do it from code in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, inspector

There is a section in size inspector  with name `Atosizing` that can set left,right,up,down layout of a control,how can i do it from code ?

Answer (score 0):

In the NSView API you can set the [autoresizing mask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html) with -setAutoresizingMask:.